# MySQL: Select Distinct from 2 different tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different tables that each have a column called **product_type**. How can I get the DISTINCT values of product_type across both tables? Just to clarify, if both tables have a product_type of "diamond" I only want it returned once. Basically as if both tables where combined and I selected distinct product_type from it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a distinct with a subquery which contains a union

```
select distinct product_type from (
    select product_type from table 1
    union 
    select product_type from table 2
) t
```

Comment: Thanks, one question.. is that "t" supposed to be at the end? what is it for? Thanks!

Comment: the T is the alias to the subquery, so, you can say t.produc_type and it'll mean "the field product_type from the subquery called T"

Comment: Do you need the outer query?  I believe the UNION will only return distinct rows.  (UNION ALL would require the outer query)

Comment: @JamesMoore Yes, otherwise the DISTINCT would not be applied

Answer (score 9):

Use distinct and union:

```
select distinct product_type from table1
union
select distinct product_type from table2
```

The union will remove duplicates when combining the results.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the UNION clause returns unique values of the field, when you want it to return ALL the values you must use UNION ALL...

```
select product_type from table_a
union
product_type from table_b
```

Comment: I think it won't work. You are missing SELECT for second table.