# Selecting distinct values from two tables

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, multiple-tables

I have two rather large databases (+1 million rows each).  Both tables have the same structure.

How can I check if each value in a column is unique across both tables?

Is there a
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT`col`) FROM tbl`
type of query that will consider BOTH tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your second table in query ???

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your title asks for one query, your question asks for a different query, and your example is different from both. What specifically are you trying to do - find all distinct values, find all non-distinct values, or find all values together with their counts? If you ask a specific question you will get answers that are more suitable for your needs - in particular the performance of the solution may differ depending on which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select Distinct from 2 different tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002452/mysql-select-distinct-from-2-different-tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `UNION` two full sets in a subquery and then select `DISTINCT col` from that.

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl2)
```

Comment: The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
UNION ALL
```

statement. It doesn't remove duplicate rows so you can see if there are any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my initial thought in pseudocode.

```
select tableOne.distinctcol
from
(select distinct col as distinctcol from tb1) as tableOne
(select distinct col as distinctcol from tb2) as tableTwo
where tableOne.distinctcol = tableTwo.distinctcol
```

Basic get a distinct list of values from each table, join them on that column.