# Sql select params from several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to modify this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    date,
    name,
    age
FROM
    reports1

SELECT DISTINCT
    date,
    name,
    info,
FROM
    reports2

Group by 
    date,
    name
```

But I want to select from `reports1` not only `date`, `name` & `age` but also `additional_info` which shouldn't be distinct. How do I do this?

Comment: look into unions

Comment: Can you share some sample  data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting distinct values from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158600/selecting-distinct-values-from-two-tables)

Comment: if you add additional column on your select which are not distinct to date, name, age combination, then it wouldn't be distinct anymore. just add the additional column from the table that you want to select

Answer (score 0):

use `JOIN` to join result of 2 tables like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r1.date,
    r1.name,
    r1.age,
    r2.info
FROM reports1 r1
Join reports2 r2 on r1.date = r2.date and r1.name = r2.name
```

For more understanding on join : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp