Query multiple tables to extract unique results only
I've been googling this for a while now but found no solution. OK I have 2 tables that look like this:
Table "main":



client_email
client_name




bla@email.com
Peter Pan


flux@xyz.com
Paul Smith



Table "registered":



client_email
client_name




yop@email.com
James Bond


flux@xyz.com
Paul Smith



Now some clients from table "main" will be in table "registered" but not all of them. Also there may be some clients who are in table "registered" but not in table "main". And lastly, the same client (email) may be multiple times in table main but only once in table registered.
Now what I want to do is a query that finds me all UNIQUE emails from both tables and the corresponding names (I don't care from which table).
I have tried:
SELECT client_email,client_name 
FROM `main` 
UNION 
SELECT client_email,client_name 
FROM `registered` 
ORDER BY client_email ASC;

but this yielded duplicate emails as it not just looks for unique emails but entries where BOTH the email and client name are unique. So having the client name spelled just slightly different in one entry (e.g., with a hyphen or accent, etc.) will result in that email being collected more than once. I can get it to work on a single table using the GROUP BY(client_email) but I can't figure out how to collect all unique emails from 2 or more tables.
Desired outcome. Based on the sample data above, I would like the following result of the query:
| client_email | client_name    |
| ------------ | -------------- |
| bla@email.com| Peter Pan      |
| yop@email.com| James Bond     |
| flux@xyz.com | Paul Smith     |


Maybe this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1002468/2058399

@user22805937 post table description of both related tables .  my problem is based on having more than 1 table, do you have more than 2 tables ?

Please provide a DBFiddle

It would help if you posted your desired outcome based on the published sample data as text

@ErgestBasha: Yes, I actually have 3, but I thought that if I find a solution for 2 I can probably extrapolate it to 3.

@P.Salmon: OK I have added the desired outcome

@HariK: DISTINCT works as long as I am only querying client_email, but once I add client_name I start to get duplicate emails. This is because the client_name entry is made on webforms by the clients themselves. So they sometimes enter their names slightly differently, e.g., if they have 2 last names with or without a hyphen, or if they have an accent then with or without the accent, etc. So when you use sth like "DISTINCT client_email, client_name" and client_name only differs slightly it will yield the same email twice.

You can group by client_email and take any client_name, if there several clients with this email.
Possible use UNION ... segment of subquery several times, how many tables do you have.
See example
select client_email,min(client_name) client_name,count(*) name_count
from(
   SELECT client_email,client_name 
   FROM `main` 
   UNION 
   SELECT client_email,client_name 
   FROM `registered` 
    -- union other tables
   UNION
   SELECT client_email,client_name 
   FROM `registered_2` 
)subU
group by client_email
ORDER BY client_email ASC;

If you can see client_name doubles for email, add column count().
And HAVING count()>1 for filter doubles.

This did the trick. Thanks very much.
Although I still don't understand why the question got downvoted by some people. What is the point of running a help forum if people get downvoted for asking question.

perhaps wrap your query and group_concat name https://dbfiddle.uk/DSWlTERj
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main,registered;

create table main(client_email varchar(20), client_name varchar(20));
insert into main values
('bla@email.com',   'Peter Pan'),
('flux@xyz.com' ,   'Paul Smith'),
('aaa'  ,   'bbb');


create table registered(client_email varchar(20),   client_name varchar(20));
insert into registered values
('yop@email.com',   'James Bond'),
('flux@xyz.com' ,    'Paul Smith'),
('aaa'  ,   'ccc');

select client_email,group_concat(client_name)
from
(
SELECT client_email,client_name 
FROM `main` 
UNION 
SELECT client_email,client_name 
FROM `registered` 
) s
group by client_email;

The sub query will dedupe on email and name and the outer query will list all the names associated with an email.

This also delivers the desired result. Thank you.
